# Machine with Nvidia card:Issues with mount command on ubuntu using hostname

Tags: mount

OS: Ubuntu14.04 64 bit
I have a strange problem occuring on machines with Nvidia cards running Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit.
The `mount` command works when using the IP address but fails when using the host name

Not-working command :

```
sudo -S mount -t cifs //share.test.com/LAB/Testing/Path1/Path2/Requisite/ -o username=blabla,password=blabla /mnt/src_shar_lnx
```

the error being

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on //share.test.com/LAB/Testing/Path1/Path2/Requisite/ ,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
   (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might
   need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program)
   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail  or so
```

The above command works seamlessly on other machines without Nvidia cards.

Working command:

```
sudo -S mount -t cifs //192.168.200.1/LAB/Testing/Path1/Path2/Requisite/ -o username=blabla,password=blabla /mnt/src_shar_lnx
```

Comment: Not a programming question. Try http://askubuntu.com

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Resolved.
installing cifs-utils solved the problem